# Best flash player on ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, flash

When I encounter a flash video in ubuntu I get an option to install 3 different swf players:

- Adobe
- Swfdec
- Gnash

Which is the most stable and preferred player?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adobe Flash.

It might be slow but it's still the best of the lot still for feature compliance and stability.

Comment: I have made progress using Gnash day to day though it needs a workaround (disable cookies for youtube) to play youtube videos. I would say stick to the adobe plugin for now.

Answer (score 3):

You forget Lightspark. But none of these alternative is really stable and they will usually work on few videos and crash on the others. If you watch lot of video I suggest you stick to Adobe Flash, if you don't watch a lot of videos and don't play online flash videos games Lightspark and Swfdec are good.

Comment: Actaully it didn't appear in the selection screen for 10.10, but thanks for your advice.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on many factors. I have the best user experience with the Adobe version.

However if you are using a 64bit version of Ubuntu, it might be tricky to set up Adobe flash. There's a shell script that helps you in that process. Download it and use these commands in terminal:

```
wget http://queleimporta.com/downloads/flash10_en.sh
sudo bash ./flash10_en.sh
```

There are couple of updates and modifications to that script you can find it [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/install-flash-10-ubuntu-linux-64bit.html#comment-150888).

Comment: I **really** wouldn't recommend using that script. Whilst not purposely malicious as far as I can tell, I can see at least one error (`killall -9 firefox` should be `killall -9 firefox-bin`). Why not just use the adobe flash PPA (`ppa:sevenmachines/flash`) that has a native 64bit build?

Comment: Nothing against the PPA it's just not known by everyone. I learned now as well. Thanks for sharing. Maybe you might write a wiki that could be beneficial for everybody who just facing the problem.

Comment: flashplugin64 has been removed from ppa:sevenmachines/flash. Any alternative?